# Calling the (IBAction) method from another class

Tags: iphone, ibaction

I need to call the IBAction method from the another class.

I am having the -(IBAction) addButtonPressed:(id)sender for button pressed action but i need the same function to be called in another method in some other class.

Comment: Post you question with some more clarity.

Comment: You also need to ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you create the method with IBAction. just create a button from code and set selector to your method. Then you can easily access the method from another class.

here I'm showing you code how to create a button with selector.

```
buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bak.png"];
UIButton *newCardBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[newCardBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:)           
                                        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then you Simply declare the method as

```
-(void) addButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {}
```

and then you can access this method from another class

Comment: thanks sandy i hav created the button thru the interface builder without changing the method can we call the ibaction method from another class. if this not possible i will go for ur answer once again thanks sandy..

Comment: No if you are using IBAtion method then you have to delegate this method with button of another class. and we cannot give two class in a single fileowner. So it will be better if you use above method

Comment: thanks sandy...-(IBAction)buttonPressed{ [self buttonClicked];} -(void)buttonclicked{//my code here } shall i use the buttonclicked method in the another class.